# Creating a VB script to write to an SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, vbscript

At the moment, I have set up an SQL database with one table with various fields.

I have not done VB scripts before and at the moment i have in my script

```
objConnection.Open _
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
"Data Source=atl-sql-01;" & _
"Trusted_Connection=Yes;" & _ "InitialCatalog=SCM-69462\SQLEXPRESS;" &
```

my InitialCatlog= I have entered the server which the database is on. This server has many different databases on already (from different students). I have set up a database X and created a table within this database. A basic table with 4 fields. With the intialCatalog string, will this locate the specific database on the server or do I need some more information? Or would I simple put `"InitialCatalog=x" &` x being the database name on the server, not the server itself?.

Comment: VB.NET has nothing to do with VBScript.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my part.

Comment: No problem. I have removed the VB.NET tag.

Answer (score 0):

According to [THE authority](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/) the connection string should look like:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

so try:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=SCM-69462\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=X;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Then test, whether adding "Trusted_Connection=Yes" helps.